# Jagged image zooms with JQuery

Tags: jquery, performance, animation

I am working on a small JQuery animation that involves several png images (text labels) "zooming" out of the page. I got the basics of the animation in place but the client has a comment that the text is "blurry" or "fuzzy". I think he is referring to the the choppiness of the animation rendering.

You can see it at the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5Mk2/2/

Any thoughts on making the animation smoother? How does it look on your end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CSS3 animations? You can use your javaScript to build the animation dynamically if you need to. They render much much smoother than position iteration and often take advantage of hardware accelerations and subpixel rendering.

There are some browser compatibility considerations ( http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation ) but I would certainly take a look.

Some useful links

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/masterclass-css-animations

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/css3_animations_vs_transitions.htm

http://www.leemunroe.com/css3-animations/

Comment: Thanks neotoxic! I will look into css transitions.